# The usage of "most of the time"

Tags: expressions

Suppose I spent my holiday visiting a city for 10 days, but I stayed in the hotel for 8 days since the bad weather.

Could I say:

> "I visited the city, but I stayed most of the time in the hotel"

Does this sound natural?

Comment: @BoldBen, if you turn your comment into an answer, it will get my vote.

Comment: @BoldBen, thanks for the comments. I really appreciate your explanation for the correction, which helps me to have some sense to avoid the similar errors. Also the explanation for the difference between _since_ and _because of_ is excellent. So, as John suggested, could you move your comment into the answer, which may be easier to be noticed by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would phrase it as "... most of the time I stayed in the hotel" or "... I stayed in the hotel for most of the time". The way you wrote it the phrase 'most of the time' interferes with the main part of the clause which is 'I stayed in the hotel'.

By the way I would use **because of** rather than **since** in the first part of your question. **Since** used in this way can't really have just a noun as the reason, it needs at least a verb as well; for example **since the weather was bad** or **since I sprained my ankle**; however you can also say **because the weather was bad**. As I hope you can see from the last suggestion **because** can replace **since** but there are cases where **since** cannot replace **because** for the reason given above.

**Since** is a good alternative where it is valid because it is shorter but, if in doubt use **because** or **because of**.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time = the majority of the available time in question.   Your usage is the same to me no matter how you order the phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is correct, but I would like to rephrase it.

"I visited the city, but I spent most of my time in the hotel."

Comment: yes, _spend_ sounds better.

Comment: Agreed.  "Stayed in the hotel" is most often used to indicate where one slept rather than where one spent their whole day.  If one goes to a city and "stays in a hotel", it does not imply never going outside, it implies renting a room and sleeping at the hotel (as opposed to a campsite, or a friend's house, for example).  "Spending time" in the hotel, on the other hand, implies spending *waking hours* at the hotel.